# PyCurses MousClick

Tags: python, curses, python-curses

```
self.stdscr = stdscr
self.initialize(**object_dict)
self.map_all_colors()
self.draw_all_views()
curses.curs_set(0) 
stdscr.keypad(1) 
curses.mousemask(1)
curses.mousemask(curses.ALL_MOUSE_EVENTS)
# Once self.interact(..) returns a value, program will end.
# This is also the *start* of any pycurses project.
while True:
    keypress = self.children[0].window.getch()
    log_t(str(keypress))
    if keypress == curses.KEY_MOUSE:
        _, x, y, _, _ = curses.getmouse()
        self.children[0].handle_mouse_click(x, y)
    else:
        response = self.interact(keypress)
        if not response:
            return 0
```

The logs indicate when the mouse is clicked, keypress returns '27' and then proceeds to move on and call self.interact() instead. how do I fix this?

I read a lot of forums, and even the documentation. Nothing works.

Comment: Are you using the built-in `curses` module, or have you downloaded a different one?  Which operating system?  What is `self.children`?

Comment: self.children is just the view window. this is a function, not a curses program. here is the full github repo https://github.com/gilbertca/pycurses/tree/refactor3

Comment: The code above is not present in that repo.  If I use `curses.ALL_MOUSE_EVENTS` in a simple curses program, `getch` returns 409, which is `KEY_MOUSE`.  We really need a complete runnable example.  What is `...window.getch()`?  Does that actually call the curses `getch`?

Comment: https://github.com/gilbertca/pycurses/blob/refactor3/base_controller.py

Comment: the code is here, in base_controller.py of the repo. yes, it calls getch. the structure is pretty complicated.

Comment: here is a class structure chart for better reference: https://lucid.app/lucidspark/141a37f7-acdd-4185-92dc-7a9bc6b9088a/edit?viewport_loc=-4026%2C-1521%2C9577%2C4550%2C0_0&invitationId=inv_85751751-d678-4b0a-b768-84a8ae0db7bf

Comment: Sorry, I checked out the repo but didn't realize I needed the `refactor3` branch.  I see it now.

Comment: That's an enormously complicated wrapper for what is a relatively simple library.  I CAN tell you that if you replace `self.children[0].window.getch()` with `stdscr.getch()`, you definitely get `KEY_MOUSE` there, instead of the VT100 escape sequence, which is what you are currently getting.  (27 is the ASCII "escape" character.)

Comment: when i do that, the program just does not run.

Comment: it gives a blank screen,

Comment: Yes, I know.  The pad apparently isn't getting refreshed.  I'm just saying that SOMEONE in the structure is doing the proper mapping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting mouse access involves not only setting the `mousemask`, but enabling `keypad`, which you have not done.  Add this after the `initialize` call and it will work:

```
self.children[0].window.keypad(1)
```